# OnEdit Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

Is there a way when you have a status column.
On that status column, when you type "yes", you capture and place each of the other columns on that row you typed yes and place them into a variable.

example:

```
a            | b            | c            | d
ingredients1 | ingredients2 | ingredients3 |status
orange       | apple        | banana       | yes
```

if status is "yes", i want to parse each ingredient into a json block.

```
if (e.range. == (if on that status column && e.range.getValue() = "yes" {
  var currentrow = e.range
   orange_var = orange;
   apple_var = apple;

}
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, it seems that from your provided information, I cannot correctly understand your question. In this case, I thought that my answer was not useful for your situation. By this, I have to delete my answer because I don't want to confuse other users. I deeply apologize for my very poor English skill again. I have to study English more.

Answer (score 2):

## SUGGESTION *[UPDATED]*

Based on your question, you want to parse each ingredient into a `JSON` block, when the `status` of the ingredient contains `yes`.

In my understanding, your **desired goal** is something like this sample `JSON` below:

```
{ ingredients1: 'orange',
  ingredients2: 'apple',
  ingredients3: 'banana' }
```

> *If I'm mistaken, please clarify your desired goal & be more specific*

### You can try this sample script below:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var res = [];
  var data = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange("A:E").getValues().filter(function (x) { return (x.join('').length !== 0) }).filter(data => { return data[4] == 'yes' || data[4] == 'status' ? data.shift() : null }).map(data => {return data.slice(0, -1)});


  for (i in data) {
    i == 0 ? null : parse(data[0], data[i], res)
  }
  
  var finalRes = "["+res.join('').replace(/}{/gm, "},{")+"]";
  console.log(JSON.parse(finalRes));
}

function parse(keys, values, res) {
  for (x in keys) {
    x == 0 ? res.push("{\"" + keys[x] + "\":\"" + values[x] + "\",") : (x < keys.length - 1 ? res.push("\"" + keys[x] + "\":\"" + values[x] + "\",") : res.push("\"" + keys[x] + "\":\"" + values[x] + "\"}"))
  }
}
```

### Alternate Script *[UPDATED]*

> This script will clear the row values after you enter `yes` on the **status** column & it will adjust if you add new columns of **ingredients**:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var res = [];
  var ss = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var statIndex = ss.getDataRange().getNumColumns()-1;

  var data = ss.getDataRange().getValues().filter(function (x) { return (x.join('').length !== 0) }).filter(data => { return data[statIndex] == 'yes' || data[statIndex] == 'status' ? data.shift() : null }).map(data => { return data.slice(0, -1) });

  if (e.range.getColumn() != ss.getDataRange().getNumColumns() && e.range.getValue() != 'yes') return;

  for (i in data) {
    i == 0 ? null : parse(data[0], data[i], res)
  }

  var finalRes = "[" + res.join('').replace(/}{/gm, "},{") + "]";
  console.log(JSON.parse(finalRes));
  clear(e.range.getRow(), e.range.getColumn(), e.range.getValue(), ss.getDataRange().getNumColumns());
}

function parse(keys, values, res) {
  for (x in keys) {
    x == 0 ? res.push("{\"" + keys[x] + "\":\"" + values[x] + "\",") : (x < keys.length - 1 ? res.push("\"" + keys[x] + "\":\"" + values[x] + "\",") : res.push("\"" + keys[x] + "\":\"" + values[x] + "\"}"))
  }
}

function clear(row, col, value, refcol) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  col == refcol && value == 'yes' ? sheet.deleteRow(row) : null;
}
```

### Sample Result:

[image]

### Reference:

- [JSON.parse()](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp)

Comment: From your answer, I could understand that I had not been able to understand the OP's question. Thank you for your answer. I think that I have to study English more.

Comment: Thank Jay. I have tested and it works, but it only works with the first row.
When i entered the 2nd row, it failed with these errors:
SyntaxError: Unexpected token { in JSON at position 144
    at parse(Code:17:26)
    at onEdit(Code:6:44)

Comment: i am actually using google forms and there is a extra 1st colum that uses Timestamp and i changed A:E and data[i][4] 
for every new submission i want to parse that specific row.

Comment: another idea is to clear the contents - the data row after each run so it only takes the 1st data row.

Comment: @chocokoala I have updated my answer. As for your other idea about **_"clearing the contents"_**, do you want to only clear every row with `yes`?

Comment: Hi Jay. 
My ultimate goal is really: user submits google form > and it will populate ONE row in google sheets. I will be the approver, and type "yes" on the status column. Next is, once i type yes, it will only parse that specific row that i typed yes to. > i will also use that json data to run a cloud function but that is next stage.
In any future, if someone request again, it should add a new row and when approved, it will also again parse only that new row. 
if that cannot be done, then, one way is to clean the row after parsing and any new request will only be a single row.

Comment: the parse output should have show the one row, not all rows

Comment: the clear row doesn't work and when i added 10 columns, one of the keys dont have quotes around it.

Comment: @chocokoala Are your columns not fixed in numbers on your **Form Response** sheet? So in reality, it is not just `timestamp`,`ingredients1`,`ingredients2`,`ingredients3` & `status`, is that correct? BTW, I have updated the **Alternate script** to only process & parse one row at a time even when you add multiple rows of data until you input **yes** on the column 5 (**status**) as seen [here](https://imgur.com/a/1X1l8O7).

Comment: Hi Jay, I can continue from there. 
Thanks a lot. You are some JS wize!